How to use the table methods in Lua
The following code seems to be correct and can probably be improved, but my problem is understanding how to use a table instead of the coords string.
I have tried
  local tbl = {}
  table.insert(tbl, .... ?)
  ...
  return table.concat(tbl)

but I can't get it to work properly table.insert
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
function list (f,min,max,nb)
   local coords = ""
   local sta = "(" .. min .. "," .. f(min) .. ")"
   coords = coords .. "(" .. sta
   for k = 1, nb do
   local x = min + (max - min) / nb * k
   local y = f(x)
   local stx = " " .. "(" .. x .. "," .. y .. ")"
   coords= coords ..stx
   end
  return coords
end
}

\def\plotcoords#1#2#3#4{%
\directlua{%
local foo = load("return function(x) return "  .."(".."#1"..")".. "end",nil,"t",math)()
tex.print(list(foo,#2,#3,#4))}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid 
\tkzDrawX[right=3pt,label={$x$}]
\tkzDrawY[above=3pt,label={$f(x)$}]
\draw[cyan,thick] plot coordinates {\plotcoords{(1-exp(-x^2))/(exp(-x^2)+1)}{-5}{5}{100}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I would like to try to rewrite the function list
\directlua{
function list (f,min,max,nb)
   local tbl = {}
   local sta = "(" .. min .. "," .. f(min) .. ")"
   table.insert(tbl, ... )
   for k = 1, nb do
   local x = min + (max - min) / nb * k
   local y = f(x)
   local stx = " " .. "(" .. x .. "," .. y .. ")"
   table.insert(tbl, ... )
   end
  return table.concat(tbl)
end
}


Can you explain what is expected, and what is wrong?

@projetmbc I can't use tbl instead of coords with table methods

The following code works. See how the insertions are done.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide, tkz-elements}

\directlua{
function list (f,min,max,nb)
  local tbl = {}

  local sta = "(" .. min .. "," .. f(min) .. ")" 
  table.insert(tbl, sta)
  
  for k = 1, nb do
    local x = min + (max - min) / nb * k
    local y = f(x)
    
    local stx = " " .. "(" .. x .. "," .. y .. ")"
    table.insert(tbl, stx)
  end
 
  return table.concat(tbl)
end
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \plotcoords }{ m m m m }{%
  \directlua{%
    local userfonc = load(
      "return function(x) return "
        .."(" .. "#1" .. ")" .. 
      "end",
      nil, "t", math
    )()

    tex.print(list(userfonc, #2, #3, #4))
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=2]
  
  \tkzGrid 
  \tkzDrawX[right=3pt,label={$x$}]
  \tkzDrawY[above=3pt,label={$f(x)$}]

  \draw[cyan,thick] plot coordinates {\plotcoords{(1-exp(-x^2))/(exp(-x^2)+1)}{-5}{5}{100}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

PS: in Lua, the ellipsis ... is for an unlimited number of arguments in the signature of a function.

I just don't understand it. That's obviously what I wrote first. I had used ...only to indicate the location of what I was missing.

Have you investigated an encoding problem of your file?

bad copy/paste I suppose

I think that the list function by @projetmbc can be made more concise and expressive (I have tested the Lua part, not the TeX part), and also absorb the load call:
local function list (expr, min, max, nb)
    -- Use heredox syntax and string:format() instead of concatenation:
    -- %s will be replaced with expr.
    local f = load (([[
        return function (x)
            return (%s)
        end
    ]]):format (expr), nil, 't', math) ()
    local tbl = {} -- no need to initialise the first row manually.
    for x = min, max, (max - min) / nb do -- you can set non-integer step.
        table.insert (tbl, ('(%f,%f)'):format (x, f (x))) -- the fewer '..', the better.
    end
    return table.concat (tbl, ' ')
end

tex.print (list ([[ #1 ]], #2, #3, #4)) -- heredoc syntax again, so that quotes do not break it.


I agree with many of your comments, but I have a problem testing with TeX. I have to use the luacode package. I don't know heredox syntax. I have used the last part of the code from local tbl with success, but the part that contains load is not working which I've kept separate.

I can do without luacode by using : \makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother
